# Closures and onclick in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, closures

I have a simple example of Javascript event bubbling on [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bigbanner/axrpcaq4/13/) (click on the man and it will bubble up to pig). How would I use a closure to get `var interval = 0;` out of the global scope, but retain the `onclick="display('sometext')"` in the html?

```
var interval = 0;

function display(animal) {
  window.setTimeout(function() { showText(animal) }, interval);
  interval = interval+300;
  window.setTimeout(function() { clear() }, interval);
}

function showText(animal) {
  $(".alGore").text(animal.toUpperCase());
    $("."+animal+"-box").css({'background-color':'#ff0'});
}

function clear(animal) {
  $(".alGore").text('');
  $("*").css({background: 'transparent'});
  interval = 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include the most relevant portions of code within your post. Links are often welcome for providing additional context, but shouldn't be the only reference.

Comment: You could wrap it in an IIFE, then add event listeners to the relevant divs instead of having the onclick property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just wrap function in another function to make a closure. But since you have two functions which you want to bind to the same closure you need an object.

Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/axrpcaq4/16/:

```
var animalBox = function(){
  var interval = 0;
  return {
    display: function(animal) {
      var that = this;
      window.setTimeout(function() { that.showText(animal) }, interval);
      interval = interval+300;
      window.setTimeout(function() { that.clear() }, interval);
    },
    showText: function(animal) {
      $(".alGore").text(animal.toUpperCase());
      $("."+animal+"-box").css({'background-color':'#ff0'});
    },
    clear: function(animal) {
      $(".alGore").text('');
      $("*").css({background: 'transparent'});
      interval = 0;
    }
    }
}();
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="center">
  <div class="pig-box center" onclick="animalBox.display('pig')">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MumugGd.png" alt="pig" class="icon">     
      <div class="bear-box center" onclick="animalBox.display('bear')">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/p7L5DHL.png" alt="bear" class="icon">    
          <div class="man-box center" onclick="animalBox.display('man')">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cKvJT7T.png" alt="man" class="icon">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="alGore"></div>
</div>
```